# Do I need the Global Site Tag (gtag.js) for optimal use with Adwords, if I'm already using Google Tag Manager to pull in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm fairly new to Google Tag Manager and handling Google Analytics along with Adwords.

I received a request to add a few event trigger scripts for Adwords and I set them up in Google Tag Manager, everything seems to be working fine. However, the requester has been persistent with the need for having gtag.js, "the global site tag is what makes tracking bulletproof when switching domains".

Everything I've read indicates that if you have Google Tag Manager, the global site tag is not necessary--regular Google Analytics would suffice. Perhaps this is different if you're also using Adwords, but I've not found any evidence yet to support the claim that gtag is needed.

I do not make the switch to gtag across all of my properties if it's unnecessary--I'd rather not risk changing settings if it's pointless to do so.

Answer (score 2):

gtag is nothing more than a slightly modified gtm snippet and a specific GTM container published by google with defaults and expectations that all configuration comes in from the dataLayer (aliased to `gtag`) as it can't know anything site specific. As it is relying on the site to provide complete and correct configuration, it makes nothing about using multiple domains bullet proof relative to an independently reconfigurable container.

If you want to, you can copy the gtag alias for your own snippet and emulate any gtag container behavior you need in your own container and you will be using the same tags gtag is using for analytics, adwords, etc.

If you let the site rely directly on the real gtag, then any mistakes made in code on the site that sends to gtag can only be fixed on the site. If you use a snippet with your own container then you can correct mistakes on the site's use of gtag by altering the container to selectively change, block, or add data to hits.

In either case, I would recommend renaming your own GTM container's dataLayer to prevent conflicts with any snippets like gtag's that try to bring in a dataLayer named `dataLayer`.

To conclude on a quote, Google's [Tag Manager and gtag.js](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7582054?hl=en) concludes with:

> If you currently use Tag Manager, you should continue to do so. Google
>   Ads and Google Marketing Platform tags are fully supported by Tag
>   Manager, and there is **no need to deploy additional gtag.js-based code**
>   on your site if Tag Manager is already in use.
>
> If you're already using gtag.js, you can always **upgrade** to Tag Manager
>   at a later date.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: In some rare occasions you will not find a solution with native Google Ads tags in GTM, and there you can still publish a gtag.js snippet in a Custom HTML tag in GTM.
Stay with GTM if you know it. It's way more versatile and flexible.